# Dado um grupo de opções, uma ao menos deve estar selecionada, usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um grupo de check-boxes que permitem selecionar flags em uma tela de busca. Acontece que, se eu permitir que o usuário desmarque todas, é certo que não existirá resultado. Dito isso, gostaria que não fosse permitido desmarcar todos os checkboxes que tenham uma classe CSS específica.

Alternativas de solução para o problema de selecionar pelo menos uma opção de um conjunto são bem vindas. Talvez, ao invés de impedir o usuário, fazer uma validação de forma que o usuário perceba que desmarcar todas as check não é permitido...

Como fazer? E o que é melhor fazer em termos de usabilidade?

Comment: Votei na tua pergunta, mas porque o teu esforço pode ser visto na resposta que deste. Contudo... seria bom adicionares algum código, nem que seja apenas a _markup_ e um JSFiddle com a mesma, à tua pergunta para que a mesma seja uma boa candidata a manifestações positivas ;)

Comment: @Zuul: Fiquei com receio de limitar respostas sobre checkboxes... talvez não seja o ideal em termos de UX usar checkboxes. Estou pesquisando sobre UX/usabilidade, e até o momento é inconclusivo... enquanto isso vou de checkboxes mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui fica mais uma alternativa

```
$(function () {
    var checkGroup = $(".check-group");
    checkGroup.on("click", function (e) {
        var marcadas = checkGroup.filter(function () {
            return this.checked;
        });
        if (marcadas.length < 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('label').addClass('alertar');
            return;
        }
        checkGroup.closest('label').removeClass('alertar');
    });
})
```

CSS

```
.alertar {
    background-color: #fbb;
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/JntCC/)

Comment: Acha que fica melhor como em termo de UX? Deixar desselecionar mostrando o fundo vermelho, ou nunca deixar o estado ficar inválido?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo, se der para desselecionar "a última" então devem ficar todas a vermelho. Assim: http://jsfiddle.net/JntCC/1/

Answer (score 4):

Eu usaria um método mais simples para não deixar nada por selecionar:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/TPqCJ/)

```
$('form').on("click", '.check-group', function (e) {
    return ($("form input:checkbox:checked").length >= 1);
});
```

<sup>**Nota:**

Dado ser uma forma muito "bruta" de controlar o utilizador, uma mensagem perto das caixas de escolha seria o recomendado se optares por esta solução.</sup>

---

Por outro lado, uma mensagem ao utilizador a dar conta do que está a acontecer seria bom:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/h7c2E/)

```
$('form').on("click", '.check-group', function (e) {
    if ($("form input:checkbox:checked").length >= 1) {
        $('form button').html('Enviar').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('form button').html('Tens que escolher o pais').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

<sup>**Nota:**

Este método é anti-frustração do utilizador, ele pode fazer o que pretende, mas o formulário não vai a lado nenhum sem que pelo menos uma opção esteja marcada.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Eu acabei fazendo como está abaixo e funciona para mim, mas não tenho certeza se é a forma mais correta, ou se existem outras melhores.

```
var checkGroup = $(".check-group");
checkGroup.on("click", function (e) {
    var anySelected = false;
    checkGroup.each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            anySelected = true;
            return;
        }
    });
    if (!anySelected)
        e.preventDefault();
    return anySelected;
});
```

Essa solução, também deixa o usuário meio frustrado, quando ele tenta desselecionar um para logo depois selecionar outro.

[Exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcUtD/)

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Permite o uso da função em outros blocos de formulários */
function checkChecks(selector, buttonToDisable) {
    var s = $(selector + ':checked'),
        b = $(buttonToDisable);
    if (s.length < 1) {
        b.prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        b.prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
    /* Dispara a verificação a cada mudança de algum checkbox */
    $('.check').on('change', function () {
        checkChecks('.check', '.sendform');
    });
```

Exemplo no [**`JSFIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/79dC6/).